# ruby-on-rails gems to determine probability curve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Is there a gem which enables you provide 3 to 4 values of known probability and generate en equation showing lognormal curve of best fit?  The curve to be used for determining different values of (y) given the value of (x)
thanks Pierre

Answer (score 0):

I didn't appreciate how hard this would be.  A third party is providing javascript to go to solve this problem.  Thanks - Pierre